# Errors while installing JsBin locally

Tags: gruntjs, npm-install, jsbin

```
C:\>npm install -g jsbin
```

I am getting following error while installing jsbin

```
> grunt build
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "concat" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

> Aborted due to warnings. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 3 npm
>   ERR! jsbin@4.0.3 postinstall: `grunt build` npm ERR! Exit status 3 npm
>   ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the jsbin@4.0.3 postinstall script. npm ERR!
>   This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   log ging output above.

Note: I have installed the following packages

- "grunt-contrib-uglify"
- "grunt-contrib-jshint"
- "grunt-contrib-concat"